# Riemannian submanifolds of $2$-Wasserstein space

Tags: dg.differential-geometry, pr.probability, riemannian-geometry, it.information-theory, optimal-transportation

In the article [*"Wasserstein Geometry Of Gaussian Measures"*](https://projecteuclid.org/journals/osaka-journal-of-mathematics/volume-48/issue-4/Wasserstein-geometry-of-Gaussian-measures/ojm/1326291215.pdf) by Asuka Takatsu the author shows how the space of d-dimensional Gaussian probability measures with non-singular covariance matrices are a Riemannian submanifold of the $2$-Wasserstein space on $\mathbb{R}^d$; by showing that the Wasserstein distance thereon can be induced by a Riemannian metric.

Are there any other examples of parameteric families of $d$-dimensional probability measures for which this is true?  I.e. for which their Wasserstein (metric) geometry coincides with a Riemmannian geometry?

Comment: There is the simple example of delta masses concentrated at one point. This seems trivial, but gives the insight that Wasserstein space has some negative curvature whenever the underlying space does.